# Does [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] return values respond to orientations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So basically my question that. Does the bounds CGRect change with the screen orientation or is it static?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tested that on iPhone simulator - it always returns the same value for all orientations

> {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}

Answer (score -1):

I created a property to return the screen bounds, taking into consideration the orientation of the device.

```
- (CGRect)boundsWithRespectToOrientation
{
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) && bounds.size.height > bounds.size.width)
        bounds = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width);
    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) && bounds.size.width > bounds.size.height)
        bounds = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width);

    return bounds;
}
```