# Monotouch UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds not updating properly

Tags: c#, ipad

In `mViewController.xib.cs` class I have a need to determine the screen height/width at any instance in time.  So i overrided the following.  I had the debugger go into these methods, what is weird is that no matter which rotations the iPad is in, it shows that my height is 1024 and width is 768, when in fact it should interchange depends on the orientation of the iPad (portrait or landscape).  Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {

        RectangleF screeninfo = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;

        float height = screeninfo.Height;
        float width = screeninfo.Width;

        return true;
    }

    public override void DidRotate( UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
    {

        RectangleF screeninfo = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;

        float height = screeninfo.Height;
        float width = screeninfo.Width;
    }
```

Comment: iPad uses objective-c buddy, not c#

Comment: Buddy, like sometimes you don't have a freakin choice.  Do you think if I have had a choice I would have used objective-c already.  Do you think I enjoy working in an environment where there are no documentations, no help, and you are all alone.  But look, I need the job, it pays the bills.

Comment: Monotouch is in c# Haoest.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Monotouch glitch, or your error; This is simply true of all iOS devices. Even doing this in Xcode:

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]));
```

yields:

```
{{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}
```

Regardless of device orientation. Just check the current device orientation and if it is landscape switch the sizes. I'm not familiar with Monotouch or C# but in Obj-C we have `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` I'm assuming the keywords are similar.

Please note: this is also true of [iPhone screens.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4546615/927947)